# Как определить, что Flash разрешен в браузере через JS?

Tags: javascript, браузер, flash

Необходимо определить, разрешено ли исполнение Flash в браузере или нет при помощи JS

Comment: За Flash не шарю, а это не то?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript

Comment: @BigTows увы нет, там определяют что Flash установлен, а в моем случае нужно определить, что Flash разрешен для исполнения

Answer (score 0):

По прошлой проблеме, с которой я столкнулся, я решил вопрос с помощью [этого скрипта](https://blog.sebastian-martens.de/technology/preload-assets-with-javascript-load-complete-callback-for-single-assets-include-swfflash/) (нужно было сделать прелоадер для в флеш без флеш). Посмотрев в исходники, нашел способ определить, разрешено ли использование флеш: пока не будет вызвана swfJSPreLoaderInit - флеш не активен, не исполняется.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого есть небольшой скрипт [Flash detection library](http://www.featureblend.com/javascript-flash-detection-library.html):

```html
<script src="http://www.featureblend.com/flash_detect_1-0-4/flash_detect.js"></script>

<script>
console.log('Flash installed: ' + FlashDetect.installed);
console.log('Version major:' + FlashDetect.major);
console.log('Version major:' + FlashDetect.minor);
</script>
```

Comment: Это не работает. Установлен - не значит что разрешено использовать. Требуется именно разрешение браузера на исполнение (Когда пользователь тыкнул "Разрешить запуск")

Comment: А если флеш установлен, то вызываете из флеша вашу JS функцию. Если функция вызвана - в этот момент флеш запущен. Если не вызвана - значит заблокирован.

Comment: Со Flash я не знаком, поэтому ищу способ через JS. Правда теперь проблема с sessionStorage - он продолжает хранить данные прошлой сессии

Comment: Ну по такому принципу работают все эти детекторы наподобие SWFObject... Способа только через JS нет.